# Can someone please explain to me the difference between those two sentences

Tags: grammar

1. Two other casualties had already taken to a nearby hospital
2. Two other casualties were already taken to a nearby hospital

Are they grammatically correct?

Comment: If the first were "Two other casualties had already *been* taken to a nearby hospital" then they would mean nearly the same thing.

Comment: The title asks for the difference. The body of the question asks about grammaticality.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the second one is correct, the first one wrong.

Unless you're saying that they like the hospital, like how "John had already taken to the food served at the hospital" or something like that.

My guess would be that "had" is often used to say that the person did this action, like "Kirito had a bath", and using it like "Kirito had eaten already" can often be replaced by "Kirito ate already" or something like that.

Answer (score -2):

The two sentences are correct and make sense, provided the proper context is found in the text where they occur.

In the first one the understanding "Two other casualties **had taken refuge** in a nearby hospital." is without problem and, I think, the only possible one that makes sense. However, with almost total certainty,  this implies that those two casualties were not so badly hurt and remained capable to use their mind and body to get to the hospital. Moreover, the verb chosen here shows that they went to the hospital essentially with the idea in mind to put themselves out of danger, their wounds not being what worried them most. This type of situation does not seem far fetched at all.

In the second one the usual situation is what is being related: two casualties, most likely unable to move and walk or kept from doing so so as to not endanger their health, and as well forbidden to walk to the hospital so as to make medical care available to them more rapidly, were transported to it (by means of a vehicle, or on a strecher carried by two persons if the hospital is quite close).
The possibility of two lightly wounded casualties able to move but ignorant of where is the hospital and therefore walked there by paramedical personel, can also be elicited from that sentence given that the context makes that clear, after or before; this is the same verb and usage as in "to take the children to school", "to take the dog to the veterinary", "take customers to their rooms in a hotel", etc.

Comment: +1 for this use of *taken*.